# Where not Exists en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause

Could anybody tell me what error I might have in my laravel query, basically what I want is to list the records of a table whose id is not related in another table. I did it in Mysql with this query: SELECT * FROM item WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM qualifications WHERE grades.item_id = item.id AND qualifications.user_id = 2);

but now I need to do this same query in laravel, I tried it this way:
[codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TF1u0.png)

and what I get is this syntax error that I do not know how to solve anymore:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFFx9.png)

I am very grateful to anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong, or in what form I make that query in Laravel.

Comment: Question in English please..

Comment: Share in english language . Try using google translater. And add code not image

Comment: `whereRaw` expects 1 or 2 parameters - either just a string with the entire where clause, or a string with placeholders and an array of bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also rewrite your query as left join like

```
SELECT i.*
FROM item i
LEFT JOIN qualifications q ON q.item_id = i.id  AND q.user_id = 2
WHERE q.item_id IS NULL
```

In query builder you can write it as

```
DB::table('item as i')
    ->select('i.*')
    ->leftJoin('qualifications as q', function ($join) use($user_id) {
        $join->on('q.item_id', '=', 'i.id')
             ->on('q.user_id', '=', $user_id);
    })
    ->whereNull('q.item_id')
    ->get();
```

Another approach which i suggest you to go with, is setup your relations and models and do it with eloquent way

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function qualifications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Qualification::class, 'item_id');
    }
}

class Qualification extends Model
{
    public function qualifications()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class, 'item_id');
    }
}
```

And then you can use  [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

```
Item::whereDoesntHave('qualifications', function ($query) use($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
})->get();
```