# Mysql pivot join fails

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table

I have following tables

**Tags**

```
id | tag_name | slug |
1 | tag1 |tag1
2 | tag1 |tag1
```

**products**

```
id | proudct_name
1|product1
2|product2
```

**product_tags**

```
id | product_id | tag_id 

1|1||1
2|1|2
3|2|1
```

i need retrieve only those product which belongs to both tag1 and tag2

```
select * from `products` INNER JOIN product_tags ON products.id=product_tags.product_id

INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id=product_tags.tag_id WHERE product_tags.tag_id=1 AND product_tags.tag_id=2
```

But my query return empty result

Comment: What is your 1 clear specific question? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will look the product that in both tables:

```
select * from `products` a where exists(select 1 from product_tags b where b.tag_id = 1 and a.product_id = b.product_id) and exists(select 1 from product_tags b where b.tag_id = 2 and a.product_id = b.product_id)
```

Comment: @zip.your answer is correct as per as concerned with mysql.do you have any idea how i can achieve this in php or laravel

Comment: @vision, i don't know laravel, however my query is using the "exists" keyword, the equivalent in laravel can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711923/where-not-exists-en-laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with `inner join`, which appears to be what you are trying.  You just need to `inner join` twice:

```
select p.*
from products p join
     product_tags pt1
     on pt1.product_id = p.id and pt1.tag_id = 1 join
     product_tags pt2
     on pt2.product_id = p.id and pt2.tag_id = 2;
```

This might be easier to code in Laravel.

Your version doesn't work because the tag cannot be both "1" and "2" at the same time -- it can have different rows with those values but only one value per row.

Also, the `tags` table is not needed for the query.